# On Android, does SQLite triggers fire other triggers?

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

Consider this SQL in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE X (Xid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Y (Yid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Xid INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Z (Yid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Blah INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS OnDeleteX
    BEFORE DELETE ON X
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Y WHERE Xid = OLD.Xid;
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS OnDeleteY
    BEFORE DELETE ON Y
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Z WHERE Yid = OLD.Yid;
    END;
```

When I delete a row in `X` I expect its linked items in `Y` **and** `Z` to be deleted too. I have verified this behavior on my PC using SQLite 3.7.11. On Android 4.0.4 this does not seem to work.

**Q:** Does SQLite on Android support cascading triggers? I.e. triggers that fire other triggers.

Also, could it be that a transaction of some kind would prevent the trigger from working?